# Chat on beta sites has an unreadable "log in" button

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, chat, beta-phase

[image: Screenshot from The Library (Biblical Hermeneutics chat)]

If you visit a chat room attached to a beta site while logged out, the *log in* message is all but unreadable, being dark grey on a dark blue background.

For example, visit [The Library](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1505/the-library) while logged out or in private browsing mode.

Comment: This issue is not only the case on beta sites, but also on chat.SE. See my [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309335/chat-login-message-is-unreadable) about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like this has been fixed at some point in time; the text is now white instead of dark gray:

[image: chatroom of Beta site with now clearly visible login message]

Comment: Howdy got that screenshot?!

Comment: You mean with the drop shadow? Cmd + Shift + 4 on a Mac, it's a built-in feature.

Comment: Aww, I cry for apple.