# Chat login message is unreadable

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, chat

When you join a chat room on chat.SE without being logged in (or using incognito mode), the message telling you that "You must be logged in to talk." is very dark and therefore pretty unreadable except the links (dark grey on dark blue).

[image: Image of the described issue]

In my opinion, the text should get modified by CSS to set to a more visible color, `#FFF` for example looks fine.